# Duty Cycling on FPOD

Tags: software, code

I am attempting to program an FPODs software to record periodically at 1 min out of 2, but when we save the specific settings file "F_SETS.txt", the POD doesn't read it automatically (as I believe the software guide indicates) and instead keeps recording continuously. The txt file contains a line of code that reads "recording = 128; 1 min of 2". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you reach out to Chelonia for an answer?

Comment: Hi Hannah and welcome! Please edit the main title so it is a specific question. As it stands, your title is a short phrase that doesn't let readers know what information you're looking for. [See guide for: "How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Hannah, we (Chelonia) have just tested this dis-continuous logging option and it is broken in the latest version of the embedded code for one of the micro-controllers.  We are working on a fix that can be applied via code on an SD card. Apologies!

Comment: hope you provide also here link to updated version for other FPOD users

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the CPODs, it is good practice to re-format your SD cards every time you deploy your FPOD to ensure all files are deleted before use. If you have other files on your SD card (like FP1 files) I think the setting files can get confused.

If you are already doing this, then reach out to Chelonia.